# iOS Get issue with Prestashop web service (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)

Tags: ios, web-services, nsurlconnection, prestashop

I do not understand this error.

If someone could help me to figure out from this infinite misunderstanding, you will enable me to sleep better ;)

I carefully followed the [documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service) and all was working fine until I switched to the iOS project.

```
 http://263DE3VI7PY5KE6O6R84RACYYEH5S5GF@192.168.1.112/prestashop/api/
```

[image]

From the iOS side I got this code and error:

[image]

```
NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@@%@/prestashop/api/", self.session.key, @"192.168.1.112"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestString]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *res, NSData *data, NSError *err){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

        NSLog(@"%@", err);
        [self didReceiveData:data];
    }];
```

All the code here is very basic, may be too much?
Did I forget 1 step to get the data from the web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@:@%@/prestashop/api/", self.session.key, @"192.168.1.112"];
```

Solved, it missed ":" :)

Comment: Hey @Adrien. I am also working on iOS project but I am not able to work out the API handling for login, register new customer, update customer. Could you please help me out. See my question here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924253/prestashop-create-customer

Answer (score 0):

By the way when I use curl I get:

```
curl -X GET -u '263DE3VI7PY5KE6O6R84RACYYEH5S5GF:' 'http://192.168.1.112/prestashop/api/customers/'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<customers>
<customer id="1" xlink:href="http://192.168.1.112/prestashop/api/customers/1"/>
<customer id="2" xlink:href="http://192.168.1.112/prestashop/api/customers/2"/>
</customers>
</prestashop>
```